# What exactly is antenna aperture? CWNA

Tags: wireless

What exactly is antenna aperture and how does this differ from antenna gain and receiver sensitivity.

I am studying for the CWNA and I am having a difficult time figuring this out.

Wikipedia doesn't help me and the other sites I have visited haven't either.

Does anyone know of an easy way to differentiate between them?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In electromagnetics and antenna theory, antenna aperture or effective area is a measure of how effective an antenna is at receiving the power of radio waves.
>   ...
>    **The larger an antenna's aperture is, the more power it can collect from a given field of radio waves.**
>   
> [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_aperture)

Aperture is a measure of how much signal a given antenna can collect.

Gain is how much amplification the antenna provides.

Receiver sensitivity is the minimum amount of signal the receiver can work with. (i.e. how softly can you talk and still be understood.)

Comment: So in other words, aperture is to antennas what receiver sensitivity is to receivers?